# rails 3 Full Calendar Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I am tackling the Rails 3 Full calendar for my site. I am a newbie but am getting there slowly :)... I have read the documentation and can see that

```
 $.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, formatString [, options ] ) -> String
```

is the option to format the date layout ( I think ). As I am new to javascript/jquery i was wondering if anyone could show me how to implement my date displayed for the week and day view as DD/MM/YYYY. If you could explain i would be very appreciative..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you found there is just a function for formatting a date for output in some specific location. For example, if you wanted a js alert dialogue to show a date object you might write

```
alert('This date object is: ' + date);
```

Which would create a dialogue showing:

*This date object is: Mon Apr 02 2012 07:45:00 GMT-0600 (MDT)*

The function you found there would allow you to format that date output string like this:

```
alert('This date object is: ' + $.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, "m-d-yy h:m" ));
```

Which would produce a dialogue that read:

*This date object is: 15-2-12 7:15*

I think maybe the option you are looking for is columnFormat

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/columnFormat/

This allows you to format the date readout at the top of the columns. In your case, add this option to your initialization which will start something like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
              editable: true,
              header: {
                  left: 'prev,next today',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
              },
              columnFormat: {
                  day: 'd/MM/yyyy',
                  week: 'd/MM/yyyy'
              },
              defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
              height: 500,
              slotMinutes: 15,
              loading: function(bool){
                  if (bool)
                      $('#loading').show();
                  else
                      $('#loading').hide();
              },
              events: "/events/get_events",
              timeFormat: 'h:mm t{ - h:mm t} ',
              dragOpacity: "0.5",
etc...
```

Check out all the Text/Time Customization options for ways to customize other parts of the calendar

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, have a much better understanding of it now.

Comment: ive tried adding the above to my calendar.js file, but when i render the page it goes blank? Am i putting it in the right place?

Comment: Check your js syntax for missing brackets or commas. Firebug is a plugin for Chrome or FF that will let you see if your js is creating errors. That columnFormat option will just be one of many in your calendar initialization, edited the answer to show a little more of what that will look like.

Comment: thanks for updating answer, ( as it happens i was putting it in the right place) so firebug gives missing } after property list- 
week: 'd/MM/yyyy' ......As far as i can see everything is in the right place ( As your example shows)

Comment: dont worry got it, missing comma after first d/mm/yy   funny how a } means comma??